# Where can I download ColdFusion 8.0 cumulative hot fix 4?

Tags: coldfusion, cfimage

I am required to continue to support an Adobe ColdFusion 8.01 server for several more months, or more.  I've come across a bug with the CFImage tag, Missing Huffman code table which causes certain JPG images to fail.  This is reported as being fixed in hot fix 4 however Adobe in the failed wisdom chose to take all CF8 hotfixes offline.  Guess where I won't be spending anymore of my money.

I've tried desperately to find a support site or even offline archive that has the chf8000004.zip file I need.  Anyone happen to have a copy?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Stack Overflow is the correct venue for this question. You might get better responses on Server Exchange. However since we are here I was in a very similar situation and found this site very useful. I know they have a large folder of CF8 hotfixes

http://www.cfmlrepo.com

Edit: I believe this link will bring you right to the CH4 for 8.0.1

https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/QBUXJCtMDDIKRZEDO4UAPFjOatzj3ajH1bHbopRJTWy/folder/NfK85LpTQu2hCpH2VqShPQ

Comment: I've found the server installs on this site, very helpful, but I'm not finding any of the hot fixes on that site.

Comment: Have you looked recently? In the 8.0.1 directory there is a hotfixes directory. Here's a direct link https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/QBUXJCtMDDIKRZEDO4UAPFjOatzj3ajH1bHbopRJTWy/folder/u3pc9w3hSLmugUy7kKmojQ

Comment: Ok, boy Adobe made this a confusing mess.  So, apparently I do have the CHF 4 updates.  I discovered that there are now 7 security hotfixes, we were only at level 2.  So, fixed all of that, we'll see if this fixes our CFImage issues.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko A patch and/or upgrading ColdFusion may not fix your image bug.  Some CMYK JPG & iPhone4 images (like the sample image on the Wikipedia CMYK JPG post) have thrown errors using CF8/9/10.  I use GraphicsMagick (free) to sanitize JPGs (convert to RGB, remove comments, etc). `GraphicsMagick Convert -colorspace rgb -strip -filter Lanczos -density 72x72 "C:\In.jpg" -interlace Line -quality 85 +profile "*" "C:\out.jpg"` (NOTE: CFExecute+GM is generally faster than CF/Java and creates smaller files.)